# Scheduling Priorities,windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, windows-7, scheduling, thread-priority

Based on msdn ,windows os schedule threads based on base prorety and uses as a boost dynamic priorety

> The system treats all threads with the same priority as equal. The
>   system assigns time slices in a round-robin fashion to all threads
>   with the highest priority. If none of these threads are ready to run,
>   the system assigns time slices in a round-robin fashion to all threads
>   with the next highest priority. If a higher-priority thread becomes
>   available to run, the system ceases to execute the lower-priority
>   thread (without allowing it to finish using its time slice), and
>   assigns a full time slice to the higher-priority thread.

From the above quote

> The system treats all threads with the same priority as equal

Does it mean that the system treats threads based on dynamic priorety?And base priorety is used just as low limit for dynamic priorety change?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Based on msdn ,windows os schedule threads based on base prorety and uses as a boost dynamic 
>   priorety

Well, you follow that with a nice text snipped that has NO SIGN OF A BOOST DYNAMIC PRIORITY.

More information about that is in the documentation - for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684828(v=vs.85).aspx is a good start.

In simple words, the scheduler schedules threads based on their current priority, and boost priority changes that, so they get scheduled differently.

Comment: I saw the article you give here.But I am interested in more detailed explanation about dynamic priorety and its interception with base priorety

Comment: Well I am quite sure you can somewhere learn how to navigate from that article to others in the same section of the documentation.

Comment: if I was finding the answer I am looking for ,I was not asking here.

Comment: @Yakov: the article TomTom links to answers the question you asked.  If you have a different question, please ask it, don't make us try to guess what it is!

Comment: @HarryJohnston-Did you see my comments?I asked the question after I read the article.My understanding - the article says that exists dynamic priorety but doesn`t explain how the scheduling is done based on it : when it is added to basic priorety and when not?is the scheduling  done only based on this priorety?etc. At least I didn`t find answeres for these questions in the article and didn`t find any link from the article ,which is helpful for the issues